# Adding bug through email with a bug tracking system

Tags: email, bug-tracking

Do you know any bug tracking tools that support adding bugs by sending an email to a specific address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In no specific order :

- [OnTime](http://www.axosoft.com/products/ontime.aspx)

  Details:

  http://www.axosoft.com/products/ontime_overview.aspx?cn=ovr_email2ticket
- [FogBugz](http://fogcreek.com/FogBugz/)

  Details:

  http://fogcreek.com/FogBugz/LearnMore.html?section=ScreenshotTool
- [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)

  Details:

  http://www.bugzilla.org/features/#email-in

Comment: I really would recommend looking at fogbugz. In all the bug tracking software I've seen this feature implemented, fogbugz does it the best.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) in the Trac repository: [trac emailfilter](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/emailfilter.py)

That said if you're familiar with Python it's very straightforward to write your own ticket creation routines for Trac.

Answer (score 0):

[Bugzilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:FAQ:Bugzilla_Email#How_do_I_set_up_the_email_interface_to_submit.2Fchange_bugs_via_email.3F).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure TestTrack Pro to monitor an email address. When email messages come in, they are automatically converted into an issue. You can optionally configure the software to respond back to the sender with specific information (ex: the defect number or assigned case number).